# How can I make a photograph database that displays the results of a query as some kind of image gallery?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am taking a database design class and for a project want to make a database of my mom's digital photos for her. I haven't dealt in application up to this point, only theory, but I have Access. Therefore, ideal answers don't suggest non-database solutions and don't assume I know much about actual database implementation. Solutions specific to Access could also be a plus. I hope that precursor saves some time and effort.

Theoretically, my mom wants to see all photos of pets from '05-'07 in raw format, and she enters an appropriate query. I suspect I can handle it up to there. However, at the moment, the best I can figure out to do is to return a column of either attachments or OLE objects. 5 clicks per photo is not ideal. I need a faster way to present the images. Opening them all in a grid of thumbnails or as a one-click-slide-show would seem the natural fit, but whatever works. How can I accomplish this?

Less important but worth consideration is the fact that, at some point, it would be great if this same type of system could be implemented on the internet for all of the family reunion photos she has taken, but I will take what I can get.

Comment: What do you mean by 'raw format'? Display images in Image control on form, unless they are PDF file type. Your question is too broad and not appropriate for SO.

Comment: A raw file format, not really important to the question just an example of sorting criteria.

Comment: "Display images in Image control on form" I don't know what this means.

Comment: While my question feels specific from my perspective, I am open to how it could be improved. I don't suppose you have a forum you could recommend? While not programming, I figured IT people would be familiar with IT topics, at least enough to help someone who knows next to nothing. Seemed a better alternative than a general forum site, anyway.

Comment: SO uses question and answer format and is intended to help with specific programming issues. You have no code for analysis and advice offered would be essentially opinions. There are many forums that are discussion format, such as accessforums.net. If you don't understand something as basic as "image control on form", perhaps your class is inadequate and suggest you spend a solid week with an introductory Access tutorial book.

Answer (score 1):

Use one form to get parameters for the query.  then use another form(more processing) or report(if printing) to show the selected pictures.  I will not cover passing parameters but here are some links.
https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/openargs/index.htm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/forms-design/apply-a-filter-when-opening-a-form-or-report

There is a complication, in Access pictures are usually stored in the attachment type.  the attachment column can hold many pictures in each record.   So if we have a table called Pictures with an attachment type column also called Pictures, then each individual picture is actually stored under Pictures.Pictures.FileData.
So to display the picture query we use a form/report with default view set to Continuous Forms  (displays many records or in this case pictures on the same page)  then in the details section of our Display form we place an attachment control and bind that control to our filtered Pictures.FileData.

[image]

[image]

Format and add functionality to taste.

Comment: Use Attachment control to allow users to manage attachments. Use Image control to just display if there is only one image saved into Attachment field. Advise not to save multiple.

Comment: Per June7's comment, if you are storing your pictures outside the database, replace the attachment control with an image control.  Then store the URL for those pictures in the picture column as type text.  set the control source for the image control to the URL in the pictures column.  Be sure to keep the URLs up to date.