# MSAccess Ole DataType does not support Bitmap image format

Tags: ms-access, bitmap, package, ole

When I try to add .bmp file in a database using (OLE Field -> Right Mouse Button -> Insert object -> Create from File -> .../image.bmp) I get Package instead of bitmap-image.
If I go to the menu (Create from new) I haven't options for .bmp file. [no bmp options image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz90v.png).
I work in MS Access and I do not use SQL or VBA/

Comment: Never seen btm as file extension for image file. How is this file created?

Comment: I get Bitmap Image listed just below Adobe Acrobat Document as first two options. Cannot replicate issue. Using Access 2010.

Comment: @June7 my bad: .bmp (bitmap image), not .btm

Comment: First you will only be able to see images in forms and reports.  Additionally Insert object creates an object which will not automatically display as a picture in a form or report.  However in a form or report you can click on the object and Access will try to open it in your computer's default program for pictures.  If you want to automatically see a picture in a form or report then My recommendation is to use the attachment type if you want to store the picture  in the database and the url(string) if you want to store the picture outside the database.

Comment: See my answer here for more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474390/how-can-i-make-a-photograph-database-that-displays-the-results-of-a-query-as-som/69477598#69477598