# Cannot display OLEDB photos from SQL Server in MSAccess form or report

Tags: ms-access

I have begun to transfer a small database from MSAccess to SQL Server. The database contains photographs and that is the cause of my problem.
Working in MSAccess, I attached, via ODBC, to the SQL Server database.
I opened dbo.person and dragged and dropped some .jpg photographs from an external directory into the photo field in the table dbo.Person. The photo field is of type varbinary(max).
I have proven that the photographs are in fact stored in the photo field by double clicking the photo field. This displays each photograph on my screen.
My problem:-
I do not know how to display the photos, which are in OLEDB format, in an MSAccess form or report.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance, thank you,
mccer

I tried tube and searching Microsoft site.

Comment: I have never had good experience using OLEObject field and controls for dynamic display of images in Access. Never tried using SQLServer field. Easier to leave images external and store file path in text field, then use Image control for dynamic display by setting ControlSource to field.

Comment: what june 7th said.  I haven't done anything with pictures in a while so i could be wrong, but it seems oleObject is the problem.  Switch the photos to the attachment type (very annoying) and they will display in an image control.  see my answer here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474390/how-can-i-make-a-photograph-database-that-displays-the-results-of-a-query-as-som/69477598#69477598

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat surprised that drag + drop into a form with an oleDB control works with SQL Server.

However, I would VERY but VERY strong suggest you don't use oleDB embedding. The reason for this is many, but one big reason is that other software, even web based or say other desktop programs will fair much better if you simply save the file as raw byte data into that `varbinary(max)` column in SQL Server.

This also tends to use the least amount of space. Image compression technology is REALLY amazing, often compressing an image by 10 or more times.

The issue with oleDB embedding is that the bmp un-compressed preview image is often LARGER than the whole high-resolution picture you saved in the database!

So, this means we need several moving parts for this to work.

First, we need to pop a file browse dialog for the user to select the picture file (sorry, no drag + drop can be used).

Next, we need some code to read the file from disk as raw bytes, and shove this result into the `varbinary(max)` column.

Last, but not least, you need "one extra" line of code in a form to display the picture from the database.

This also means we will use the new picture control. This new control (introduced into Access 2010) is rather nice since it can render most picture formats, and that includes rendering data from SQL Server `varbinary(max)` columns.

So, assuming the form is based on a linked table to SQL Server, and one column is `varbinary(max)`.

So, we will have to pop the file dialog to browse to a picture.

So, let's drop in a text box (called txtFile). And beside that a button to browse to a file.

So, we have this:

[image]

And the code behind for the select file button is this:

```
  Private Sub cmdFile_Click()
  
     Dim f As FileDialog
     Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
     
     f.Show
     
     If f.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Me.txtFile = f.SelectedItems(1)
     End If
  
  End Sub
```

And now we have this:

[image]

Now, beside the above, I have a button to save the picture selected.

In "production" code no doubt these 2 steps would be combined into a simple and single file selection, save and display.

So, beside above, after we select the file, we have a save to database button.

That code is this:

```
  Private Sub cmdSaveToDB_Click()
  
     Dim MyImageB() As Byte
     
     MyImageB = GetFileBytes(Me.txtFile)
     
     Me!MyImage = MyImageB
     Me.Dirty = False
     
     Me.Image1.PictureData = Me.Recordset!MyImage
     
  End Sub
```

And one more routine:

```
  Public Function GetFileBytes(ByVal path As String) As Byte()
  
      Dim lngFileNum      As Long
      Dim bytRtnVal()     As Byte
      lngFileNum = FreeFile
      
      If LenB(Dir(path)) Then ''// Does file exist?
          Open path For Binary Access Read As lngFileNum
          ReDim bytRtnVal(LOF(lngFileNum) - 1&) As Byte
          Get lngFileNum, , bytRtnVal
          Close lngFileNum
      Else
          Err.Raise 53
      End If
      
      GetFileBytes = bytRtnVal
      
      Erase bytRtnVal
  
  End Function
```

So, all of the above routines can be used for the desired result.

So, I broken this out to multiple steps, and as noted, in practice, the user would browse to a picture, select it, and then code would save to database and display it, and do so in one operation.

So, above looks like this:

[image]

Note that if the form has/allows record navigation, then you need to add to the forms on-current event since the new image control does not automatic display the image for you, even if you bind the new image control to the column behind (hence, don't bind the image control - leave it un-bound and use code to load/fill the picture).

So, the one line of code, either at form load time (for forms that load to one record), or using form on-current event, you need this one line of code for the picture to display automatic:

```
     Me.Image1.PictureData = Me.Recordset!MyImage
```

As noted, we are NOT using the older oleDB picture control in the form, but using the newer image control. That is this image control from the ribbon:

[image]